# Form maxlength field validation using angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

How to validate the **username** field with maxlength or minlength using angular2 **without using the formbuilder**.

I tried in the following way, but not working

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="person" item-left class="placeholder-icon"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label floating primary>Username</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.username" ngControl="username" type="text" #username="ngForm" ng-minlength="5" required>
        </ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <div [hidden]="username.valid || username.pristine">
        <p *ngIf="username.errors && username.errors.required" danger padding-left>
            user name is required
        </p>
        <p *ngIf="username.errors && username.errors.minlength" danger padding-left>
            min length atleast 5
        </p>
      </div>    
<ion-item>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add the `minlength` to your input element. This way the `MinLengthValidator` directive will be automatically added and registered as a validator:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.username"
       ngControl="username" type="text"
       #username="ngForm" minlength="5" required>
```

Comment: I am trying to add validation for password field with pattern="/^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*? ]).*$/". But this not working